# How to fully automate the package Copyright property in a .csproj file?

Tags: c#, msbuild

In every new project that will have a package there is a `Copyright` property. For anyone who wants to copyright their work they need to look up the format and then enter the copyright string. It seems that this could be done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I did this I decided that this should be the default for all new projects. Why would you ever manually type the copyright property?

This is an example for United States Copyright string:

`<Copyright>Copyright $([System.DateTime]::Now.Year) $(Company)</Copyright>`

Comment: Maybe because Copyright strings vary: fixed start date, multiple holders, the term "All Rights Reserved", the need for a "(C)", or no copyright at all ... - having all that said I'm no laywer by any means ;-)

Comment: Absolutely, I'm just documenting a generic US copyright that could be used as a company default that never needs to be updated manually. Survives time and company name changes.